# How to code the REST resource dataset of an Azure Data Factory in Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to code an Azure Data Factory in Terraform, but I am not sure how to code this REST dataset:

```
{
"name": "RestResource1",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "API_Connection",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "RestResource",
    "schema": []
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
```

}

I don't see one in the azurerm documentation.  Can one instead use an azurerm_data_factory_dataset_http resource instead?

Comment: That looks like the request body content for the REST API, which is indeed an argument for `azurerm_data_factory_dataset_http`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_rest` - Does not currently exist.
>
> `azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_web` - This only support a web
> table and not a REST API endpoint and can't be used with the Azure
> integrated runtime.

As I tried to create the linked service using rest and http it always redirected to create a web table using terraform. Hence, for now the fix for this is to use `azurerm_data_factory_linked_custom_service`.

**Here, is the example:** How to create a Custom Linked service :

```
provider "azurerm" {

  features{}

}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {

  name     = "Your Resource Group"

}



data "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {

  name                = "vipdashadf"

  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

}



resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_custom_service" "example" {

  name                = "ipdashlinkedservice"

  data_factory_id =   data.azurerm_data_factory.example.id

  type = "RestService"

  description = "test for rest linked"

  type_properties_json = <<JSON

  {

            "url": "http://www.bing.com",

            "enableServerCertificateValidation": false,

            "authenticationType": "Anonymous"

}

JSON

annotations = []

}



resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_http" "example" {

  name                = "apidataset"

  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  data_factory_name   = data.azurerm_data_factory.example.name

  linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_custom_service.example.name



  relative_url   = "http://www.bing.com"

  request_body   = "foo=bar"

  request_method = "POST"



}
```

**Outputs:**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dAfpVWc.png]

**Linked Service** - `ipdashlinkservice` type Rest Connector

[image]

**Dataset:** `apidataset`

[image]

You could find the same stated in the **GitHub discussion:** Support for Azure Data Factory Linked Service for REST API [#9431](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9431)

Comment: I was going to use azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_web, but this might work better.

Comment: I used this, but terraform is giving me an "Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token" and it is highlighting the <<.  Not sure why this is happening.
EDIT: Retyping the <<JSON line seems to have cleared that up.

Comment: @Michael Robinson Ah, could you please post the full error message or snips, so I could help ?

Comment: If you're talking about my comment of yesterday, it was solved simply by retyping the line.  Cutting and pasting from above must have introduced some unseen character.

Comment: Lovely!! great that it worked :)